# Preconfigured VM Appliance / Linux Distribution With Infrastructure for Development Teams

Tags: installation, virtual-machine, infrastructure, appliance

Does anyone know a VM Appliance (or Linux distribution) that provides a pre-configured and adaptable development infrastructure for small teams.

The idea is to have an easy configuration where one says I want a Trac + GIT + Maven + Hudson, Confluence + Jira + SVN or FogBugz + Mercury setup [*] and either the VM for the project or a project within the VM / Distribution is configured and everything is tied together.

I know of either older projects that are not maintained and updated anymore (VMware Appliance Market Place, some very good examples, but unmaintained for three years), or of focused projects that only support one aspect (e.g. [Trac](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/trac), or [agile dev / testing](http://www.coveros.com/research/research_stack.php)).

[*] I know the examples represent a very wide spectrum, but to give the idea =)

Answer (score 2):

Don't be so quick to overlook TKL.

Using a few of their appliances as bases and then applying TLKPatches to those bases will accomplish exactly what you're asking. The problem is that creating TKLPatches isn't exactly a walk in the park. It's straightforward, but it can be tedious. Look for other patches in their forums as examples.